# Delphi Indy 9 and 10: TraceSSL: What do the logs look like for TLS?

Tags: delphi

We are doing some testing, both with Indy 9 (which we are locked into for some projects) and Indy 10.

We need to verify that we are making TLS connections.

Using the TraceSSL flag, we are looking at the logs.

How can we tell (for certain) that a connection is TLS 1.0?

This appears, to us, to be only SSL v3 (but why does it mention TLS on the last line?):

```
SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
Cipher: name = RC4-SHA; description = RC4-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      
Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1; bits = 128; version = TLSv1/SSLv3;
```

This one, we think is TLS 1.0, but the log is anything but clear (why does it say SSLv3 on the last line?):

```
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server done A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
Cipher: name = DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA; description = DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      
SSLv3 Kx=DH      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1; bits = 256; version = TLSv1/SSLv3;
```

The below log is Indy10, and based on cipher, we are sure it is TLS, but the log says SSLv3 all over:

```
SSL Version: sslvTLSv1_2
Resolving hostname #####.
Connecting to ############.
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server certificate A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server done A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
Cipher: name = AES128-SHA256; 
description = AES128-SHA256           
TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      
Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  
Mac=SHA256
; bits = 128; version = TLSv1/SSLv3;
```

Finally, if none of the above is TLS, then what do we need to know, about SSLOptions, and other flags, to get this up to TLS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To use TLS v1, you need to set the `SSLOptions.Method` to `sslvTLSv1` (in Indy 10, you can alternatively enable the `sslvTLSv1` in the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property, which replaces the `SSLOptions.Method` property).

Comment: Thank you!  sslvTLSv1  forces always TLS, right?  Is that safe?  Will the logging then be crystal clear that it is TLS and not SSL?

Comment: Yes, `ssvTLSv1` is specifically TLS 1.0 only.  Newer versions of Indy also support TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2.  I have no clue what the effect it will have on the log.  That is OpenSSL's log, not Indy's.

Comment: The problem we have at this point is the log. The log is full of references to SSLv3, when we think it is actually doing TLS. What should we do??  (revising OP in 1 min)

Comment: You are clearly using TLS: `SSL Version: sslvTLSv1_2`. TLS is just SSL 3.x renamed when TLS was standardized.  Internal to OpenSSL, TLS 1.0 is SSL 3.1, TLS 1.1 is SSL 3.2, TLS 1.2 is SSL 3.3, etc.  So it makes sense that OpenSSL might reuse some of its internal SSLv3 code to handle TLS. If you don't like the way the log looks, the only way to change it is to edit and recompile OpenSSL yourself.

Comment: It took some mins, but we see now that the only way to know the TLS ver in use is to look at the cipher used, and then to look that up on the openssl cipher list. So that part, at least, is under control.

Answer (score 0):

It took some mins, but we see now that the only way to know the TLS ver in use is to look at the cipher used, and then to look that up on the openssl cipher list. So that part, at least, is under contro.

Cipher list: https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html